# How to build an app similar to taskbucks?

Tags: android, ads, inmobi, tapjoy

I want to build an app similar to taskbucks which shows list of tasks that user alongwith coins users gets for performing that task. On server side I am using codeigniter and client I can use ionic and native android. I tried a lot googling but unable to find answer to my following queries:

1. How do I get list of ads only relating to installing apps or some tangible actions instead of just clicking banner or interstitial ads.
2. I will have incentivized traffic so need to show users how many coins they get when perform this task.
3. Can I get information on my server of what actions have been performed by which user and how much money I have earned for this action and how many coins has been awarded to user.
4. Can I integrate with multiple ad networks at the same time for same app.

I have gone through number of ad networks but tried in detail with Tapjoy and inmobi only.